# Why can't I add Class for a dialog in VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I want to write a simple minesweeper as some practice. I created a dialog and I want to create a class to relate variables to the input for edit box. However when I right clicked the dialog, I cannot select "create a class".

Here is the screenshot. There wasn't any error so I don't know what to provide. If you need any extra information please let me know.

[image: cannot select "Add Class"]

Comment: Isn't there a class corresponding to the created dialog already?

Comment: I don't think so as I didn't find any classes in the Resource Explorer. I tried the Add Variable Button and an error pop up, saying "Did not find a dialog class with the specified ID 'IDD_CUSTOM'"

Comment: Have you created a MFC application or a regular Win32 project?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ When you add a new dialog through the resource editor, it doesn't automatically create a class for it.

Comment: @zett42 I created a windows desktop application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a class for a dialog of a Windows Desktop application. A Windows Desktop application uses only basic Win32 API which does not provide a class framework.

You have to choose the **MFC application wizard**, when creating a new project. From this wizard select "**dialog based**" to create the most basic application. It will automatically add a dialog with a corresponding class.

You only need to "Add Class" when adding more dialogs to the application.